# QCustomplot - Hide / Show selected graph

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I'd like to hide / show a graph by selecting it directly on the plot. What I have in mind is something like this:

```
myPlot->graph(graphIdx)->setVisible(false);
```

in which `myPlot` is a `QCustomPlot` widget.

My question is: is there a way to get the index `graphIdx` of the selected graph? It might be trivial but honestly I cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance

A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just take pointer from QCustomPlot::selectedGraphs().

```
auto ololo = new QCustomPlot();
...
foreach(QCPGraph* gr, ololo->selectedGraphs()){
    gr->setVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the function [`QCustomPlot::selectedGraphs`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCustomPlot.html#ad2a0493bdd01e7aa99a4209ae3a5b67b) that returns a `QList<QCPGraph *>` (in your case it should have exactly 1 element). You can directly call `setVisible` on those pointers. You may want `QCustomPlot::selectedPlottables` instead as the documentation suggests.